# python selenium to scrape data from asos - need a better approach

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

Hi I'm new to Python and crawling. I've been researching and going over Stackoverflow and come up with Python + Selenium to open Webdriver to open the URL and get the page source and turn it into the data I need. However, I know there's a better approach (for example, scraping w/o selenium, not having to scrape page source, posting data to ASP, etc) and I hope I can seek some help here for an educational purpose.

Here's what I'd like to achieve.

- Start:
  http://www.asos.com/Women/New-In-Clothing/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=2623
- Obtain: product title, price, img, and its link
- Next: go to next page if there is, if not, output

BEFORE you go into my code, here is some background information. Asos is a site that uses pagination so this is related to scraping through multipages. Also, I tried without Selenium by posting to http://www.asos.com/services/srvWebCategory.asmx/GetWebCategories
with this data:

```
{'cid':'2623', 'strQuery':"", 'strValues':'undefined', 'currentPage':'0', 
'pageSize':'204','pageSort':'-1','countryId':'10085','maxResultCount':''}
```

but there's no return I get.

I know my approach is not good, I'd much appreciate any help/recommendation/approach/idea! Thanks!

```
import scrapy
import time
import logging

from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from asos.items import ASOSItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



class ASOSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "asos"
    allowed_domains = ["asos.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.asos.com/Women/New-In-Clothing/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=2623#/parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=204&sort="

    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        view_204 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-count-bottom']/a[@class='view-max-paged']")
        view_204.click() #click and show 204 pictures
        time.sleep(5) #wait till 204 images loaded, I've also tried the explicit wait, but i got timedout 
        # element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 8).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "category-controls bottom"))) 
        logging.debug("wait time has reached! go CRAWL!")

        next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='page-skip']/a")

        pageSource = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source) # load page source instead, cant seem to crawl the page by just passing the reqular request
        for sel in pageSource.xpath("//ul[@id='items']/li"):
            item = ASOSItem()
            item["product_title"] = sel.xpath("a[@class='desc']/text()").extract()
            item["product_link"] = sel.xpath("a[@class='desc']/@href").extract()
            item["product_price"] = sel.xpath("div/span[@class='price']/text()").extract()
            item["product_img"] = sel.xpath("div/a[@class='productImageLink']/img/@src").extract()
            yield item

        next.click()
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Seems like a better post for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). What programming problem are you having?

Comment: Since you ask for recommendation, I think, you might gain some practical knowledge watching Draps tutorial's on youtube, especially [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVwj2BCb9GI&list=PL1A2CSdiySGLtKwqBnqj9BON6QQjWkP4n&index=11), basically the tutorials on web scraping.

Comment: @ChrisP, any way to scrape without selenium? e.g. by posting this data set to [link] http://www.asos.com/services/srvWebCategory.asmx/GetWebCategories {'cid':'2623', 'strQuery':"", 'strValues':'undefined', 'currentPage':'0', 
'pageSize':'204','pageSort':'-1','countryId':'10085','maxResultCount':''}
?

Comment: @3shimi, the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module is very popular and has a `post` method. It can also handle cookies.

Comment: @ChrisP, thanks, any successful example to this specific site through post? i cant seem to get it to work.